# How using form in ListView Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create an action for the ListView, the action will be to delete or to change a parameter in the table in my model, for example, disable user, using checkbox.
If I selected all them and click this botton, It'll be delete all selected.

**views.py

```
class AccountsManagementView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    """
    Class Based View para a manipulação de usuários.
    """
    model = User
    template_name = 'accounts/accounts_management.html'
    context_object_name = 'users'


    def get_queryset(self):
        return User.objects.all()

class DeleteUser(DeleteView):
    model = User
    success_url = reverse_lazy('accounts:accounts_manager')
```

**urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ListView dos Usuarios
    url(r'^$', views.accounts_management, name="accounts_manager"),
    # Deletar Usuario
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/deleteuser/$', views.delete_user, name="delete_user"),
    # Add Usuario
    url(r'^adicionar_usuario/$', views.accounts_form, name="accounts_form"),
    # Update Usuario
    url(r'^editar/(?P<username>[\w_-]+)/$', views.account_edit, name="accounts_edit"),
    # Visualizar perfil usuario
    url(r'^visualizar/(?P<username>[\w_-]+)/$', views.account_view, name="accounts_view"),
]
```

templates/accounts_management.html

```
<form action="" method="post">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <div class="panel-title">
            <a href="{% url 'accounts:accounts_form' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success mb_sm">
                <i class="fa fa-user-plus" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true"></i> Add User
            </button></a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger mb_sm">
                <i class="fa fa-user-times" aria-hidden="true" aria-hidden="true"></i> Del User
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped" id="datatables__example">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="col" class="-colaction-checkboxumn">
                        <span>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="account-users" id="action-toggle" hidden="hidden"/>
                            <label for="action-toggle"></label>
                        </span>
                        </th>
                        <th>Foto</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Usuário</th>
                        <th>Grupo</th>
                        <th>E-mail</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Ativo</th>
                        <th>Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    {% for usuario in users %}
                        <tr class="row1">
                            <td class="action-checkbox">
                                <input class="action-select" id="_selected_action" name="account-users" type="checkbox" value="{{ usuario.id }}" hidden="hidden"/>

                            </td>
                            <td scope="row">
                                <div class="sidebar-user__avatar">
                                    <img src="{{ usuario.imagem|thumbnail_url:'user_image' }}">
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <a href="{{ usuario.get_absolute_url }}">{{ usuario.name }}</a>
                            </td>
                            <td>{{ usuario.username }}</td>
                            <td>{% if usuario.groups.all.0 %}
                                {{ usuario.groups.all.0 }}
                            {% else %}
                                <span>Não Atribuído</span>
                            {% endif %}</td>
                            <td>{{ usuario.email }}</td>
                            <td>
                                {% if usuario.is_authenticated %}
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-lg" style="color: #4aa74e;" aria-hidden="true"></i> Online
                                {% else %}
                                    <i class="fa fa-circle-o fa-lg" style="color: #ac2925;" aria-hidden="true"></i> Offline
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                {% if usuario.is_active == True %}
                                    {% comment %}<img src="{% static 'assets/ico/correct-45-45.png' %}">{% endcomment %}
                                    <a href="#" class="col-xs-1"> <i class="fa fa-check fa-lg" style="color: #4aa74e;" title="Desativar Conta"></i></a>
                                {% else %}
                                    {% comment %}<img src="{% static 'assets/ico/incorrect-45-45.png' %}">{% endcomment %}
                                    <a href="#" class="col-xs-1"> <i class="fa fa-ban fa-lg" style="color: #ac2925;" title="Ativar Conta"></i></a>
                                {% endif %}
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

                                <a href="{% url 'accounts:accounts_edit' username=usuario.username %}"> <i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" style="color: #464960;" title="Editar Conta"></i></a>

                                <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

                                <a href="{{ usuario.get_absolute_url }}"> <i class="fa fa-eye fa-lg" style="color: #ec971f;" title="Visualizar Conta"></i></a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    {% endfor %}
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is make the form return a list of the pk's of the objects you want to delete.

Then you do something like:

```
def delete_view(request):
    if request.method == "post":
        data = [] # Array of pks
        User.objects.filter(pk__in=data).delete()
```

That should do what you're asking.

If that dosen't help you; maybe google bulk delete django. Seems to be a feature that was present in the past, but is no longer supported.

Comment: Thanks for help H.Boe. I could do this and I could do with class based View in ListView method POST.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the generic.UpdateView for an example of a CBV using a post() method.  It is there where you would bring in a form, validate the input, and process - in your case looking at the value of each check box and handling the record accordingly.

You probably won't need to break your logic into as many methods as the generic View does, unless you wish to make it reusable.